# How to use Tuples in Anchor lang

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang, cargo

What am I doing wrong? Is that not how we use tuples in rust?

Account:

```
#[account]
pub struct UserLedger {
    pub list: Vec<(String, u32)>,
}
```

Error Message:

`Error: Type not found: {"type":{"defined":"(String,u32)"}}`

Comment: For anyone running across this today and wondering about the current status of tuples: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12116/does-anchor-support-tuple-structs/12117#12117

Answer (score 4):

tuples are not implemented in anchor so far (`version: 0.27.0` at time of writing), you can use a `struct` in your case.

```
#[account]
pub struct UserLedger {
    pub list: Vec<MyTuple>,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
struct MyTuple {
    my_string: String,
    my_u32: u32
}
```

for an `enum` as well you are not allowed to use tuples, which is quite common, but you can use it like this:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub enum Grade {
    Pass { value: u64 },
    Fail { value: u64, next_attempt: MyDate },
}
```

Comment: In your fix, `pub list: Vec<(String, u32)>` should be `pub list: Vec<MyTuple>`?
`

Comment: thanks @Nawaz fixed.