# Does Anchor support tuple structs?

Tags: anchor

I have an anchor program wherein I'm defining custom types in 3 ways:

As an alias:

```
pub type MyType = u64;
```

As a struct:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct MyType2 {
    pub some_field: u64;
}
```

As a tuple struct:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct MyType3(pub u64);
```

The alias and normal struct work perfectly. The tuple struct compiles, but when I try to use it via typescript  I get `IdlError: Type not found: {"name":"my_field","type":{"defined":"MyType3"}}`. I found [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/how-to-use-tuples-in-anchor-lang) which seems to indicate Anchor doesn't support tuples in general, however it is from 1.5 years ago and with an older version of Anchor (0.27) than I'm using (0.29), so want to double check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging a bit more in the anchor github, I realized a PR adding exactly this was merged literally last week: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2824

I'm guessing this means anchor v0.30.0 will support them when it comes out!